# On Rails 2.3.8 paragraph tag, <p>, inserted automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

I just want to do like this.

```
<p><form blabla></form><form blabla></form></p>
```

so, on rails 2.8.3 I wrote like this.

```
<p>
<%- form_tag blabla -%><%- end -%>
<%- form_tag blabla -%><%- end -%>
</p>
```

but the result is like this.

```
<p></p>
<form blabla></form>
<form blabla></form>
<p></p>
```

How can I avoid paragraph tag automatically inserted?

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid html to nest form tags inside a p tag so your browser is trying to fix it for you.    http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

You can verify that the browser is altering this this by:

```
telnet localhost 3000
GET /wherever/this/is HTTP/1.0
```

And you will see something like:

```
<p>
<form action="/dog" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="HxzAQS/UMwdXmcMzX+qk9eV49JCmwnds9bekrr3YKj0=" /></div></form><form action="/dog" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="HxzAQS/UMwdXmcMzX+qk9eV49JCmwnds9bekrr3YKj0=" /></div></form></p>
```